# When running Firefox from JPM CSS doesn't load

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I am testing a Firefox extension using `jpm run`. I am using Firefox 42.0 on Windows 10.

It seems if I test my extension, all pages appear to have SSL certificate issues and the CSS doesn't load for a number of pages.

For example, the Firefox homepage (https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/windows-10/welcome/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_content=firstrun) looks like this:
[image]

And Twitter (https://twitter.com/) looks like this:
[image]

Also, Facebook gives an SSL certificate warning:
[image]

It works fine if I run Firefox normally however I get the above issue if I run Firefox or Firefox Developer Edition using `jpm run`.

I thought it was something my extension was doing, so I tested it with the [Mozilla JPM Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29) and got the same issue.

How can I get Firefox to load properly using jpm?

**EDIT:** There is a work around. If I run `jpm run --profile <path_to_profile>` (specifying my Firefox profile) it will work fine (thanks "Tew" from #extdev on irc.mozilla.org. I suppose this means the issue is with the profile jpm is using for Firefox?

Still looking for a proper solution though.